# Return date from function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try write function with three arguments (both string) where in return i get date in format YY/MM/DD.

It is my code:

```
create FUNCTION x(a string, b string, c string) RETURN date IS
    rec date;
  BEGIN
    rec := to_date(WHAT ADD IN THIS PLACE,'YY/MM/DD'');
    RETURN rec;
  END;
```

I don't know what i must add as argument in to_date function.
Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: What do the arguments a, b and c mean? Are these the year, month and day and then you want to generate a date with these inputs?

Comment: yes, it is - this is year,month and day.

Comment: So you just want to concatenate the arguments together, with a slash between each? You really have 2-digit years - and if so, you want YY not RR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rec := to_date(a||'/'||b||'/'||c,'YY/MM/DD');
```

I hope it helps.